# Lazy loading BelongsTo relation with Castle Active Record?

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading, castle-activerecord

I have the following mapping for a Relation in Castle AR

```
[BelongsTo("EVENT_ID", Lazy = FetchWhen.OnInvoke)]
        public EventType PayEvent
        {
            get
            {
                return m_PayEvent;
            }
            set
            {
                m_PayEvent = value;
            }
        }
```

But the Relation is fetched even if the property is not invoked.Is there anything missing here? I am using SessionScope as well.

Comment: try http://www.mail-archive.com/castle-project-users@googlegroups.com/msg04298.html

Comment: I have tried this one but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It works for me](http://code.google.com/p/mausch/source/browse/trunk/LazyTests/Tests.cs?spec=svn343&r=343#93). Make sure you have the entity marked as lazy and the properties and methods are all virtual.

Answer (score 0):

in addition lazy-loading for BelongsTo relations does not work if you set NotFoundBehaviour to Ignore

Sample:

```
[BelongsTo("EVENT_ID", Lazy=FetchWhen.OnInvoke, NotFoundBehaviour:=NotFoundBehaviour.Ignore)]
```

Answer (score -3):

You cannot enable lazy loading with belogs to relationship.
See [here](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/v1rc1/usersguide/lazy.html).
You can implement it yourself.
Store the ID in your model and then:

```
    public ServicePlan PreviousServicePlan
    {
        get
        {
           if (previousServicePlan == null)
                previousServicePlan = ActiveRecordMediator<ServicePlan>
                    .FindByPrimaryKey(PreviousServicePlanId, false);

           return previousServicePlan;
        }

        private set 
        {
            previousServicePlan = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's old documentation (for ActiveRecord RC1). Lazy BelongsTo has been implemented since.